# Передача void* параметра в функцию

Tags: c++

Имеется функция:

```
void MyFun(void *Array){...}
```

Как определить какой тип данных получен, для последующего вычисления его размера (sizeof())

Comment: В общем случае никак

Comment: Нужно код переписать. Или дописать размер массива:
<pre>void MyFun(void *Array, unsigned long ArraySize){...} </pre>
Либо выкручиваться более хитро - например, с помощью шаблонных ф-ций.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Угу.

void * - просто указатель на что-то. Непонятно что.

Число ли это, строка, массив, структура - компилятор знать не будет. Потому и применяют типы "указатель на что-то известное", если это надо.

Если же нужно в одну функцию передавать разные штуки (а надо ли так делать?), то нужно функцию как-то уведомлять, что же ей дали на переваривание.

Answer (score 2):

Ни размер, ни тип вы не определите, только если это будет строка, а строка оканчивается нулем.

Comment: Досадно! Спасибо!